# JavaScript element creation differences resulting in jquery.ui.autocomplete element undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to dynamically create an input element and attach a jquery.ui autocomplete control to it before adding it to the DOM. The way I normally create dynamic elements seems to be creating an `Cannot read property 'element' of undefined` error, and I cannot figure out why.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  const inputFromTemplate = createFromTemplate(`<input></input>`);

  console.log(input);
  console.log(inputFromTemplate);

  $(input).autocomplete({
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  });

  $(inputFromTemplate).autocomplete({
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  });

  content.append(input);
  content.append(inputFromTemplate);
});

function createFromTemplate(template) {
  const htmlTemplate = document.createElement('template');
  htmlTemplate.innerHTML = template;

  return htmlTemplate.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

In the above code sample, when I create an `input` element using the `document.createElement('input')` method, the autocomplete control attaches without a problem.

When I create an `input` element using my own `createFromTemplate` method, it throws the above error.

Both elements appear the same when logged out to the console, but it appears that the autocomplete control is attaching before the `console.log` fires (you can see this by running as is, then commenting out the `.autocomplete` lines of code and seeing the difference in the `input` code logged out to the console).

I would assume that my understanding of how jquery attaches controls to elements is flawed, as I can't see why there would be a difference between the two.

(Note: Yes, this is a simple reproduction, the reason I want to use a function like `createFromTemplate` is because the actual input is part of a larger html template, so chaining together `document.createElement` methods isn't going to happen).

EDIT:
Just to address the issue of it working when the element is attached to the DOM first, unfortunately that isn't an option in the case of the project I'm working on. [Something akin to this issue was reported and fixed in a previous version of jquery.ui back in 2012](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8858), so it might well be a bug with the library

Comment: If you re-arrange your logic so you define the autocomplete *after* appending the elements to the DOM it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9bsyemzd/ - I'm unable at this point to explain why this difference appears between methods of creating the element, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yep, but in my case, that isn't an option. It's a work around that would involve re-writing a very large chunk code, what I don't understand is why it's an issue. There was a bug listed in 2013 (I think) on the jquery bug board that listed the same type of issue with unattached elements, but it was resolved. It's something specific to the way I'm creating the element that seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: Is this what you want @DarkHippo ? https://jsfiddle.net/6k2do9vb/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Nice try, but no, as I can't append the generated element to the DOM before attaching the autocomplete control (see above comment)

Comment: When I run your code, I do see the error: `jQuery.Deferred exception: this.menu is undefined ` The widget usually needs the element in the DOM. Will check to see if this the element can be created beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a quick read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

> A DocumentFragment is not a valid target for various events, as such it is often preferable to clone or refer to the elements within it.

> **HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<template id="template">
  <div>Click me</div>
</template>
```

> **JavaScript**

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const template = document.getElementById("template");

function clickHandler(event) {
  alert("Clicked a div");
}

const firstClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
firstClone.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
container.appendChild(firstClone);

const secondClone = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
secondClone.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
container.appendChild(secondClone);
```

> **Result**

> `firstClone` is a DocumentFragment instance, so while it gets appended inside the container as expected, **clicking on it does not trigger the click event**. `secondClone` is an HTMLDivElement instance, clicking on it works as one would expect.

When trying to initialize Autocomplete, event binding will fail. This may be why you are seeing various different errors and why other elements are working and elements in `template` are not.

So let's test as they advise, the way you tried, and with some other possible solutions.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  var inA = document.createElement('input');
  var inB = createTempObj("<input>");
  var inC = createFromTemplate("<input>");
  var inD = document.getElementById("template").content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  var m1 = menuFromTemp();

  console.log("Init Autocomplete 1");
  console.log("HTML", inA);

  initAutoComplete(inA);

  console.log("Init Autocomplete 2");
  console.log("HTML", inB);

  initAutoComplete(inB);

  console.log("Init Autocomplete 3");
  console.log("HTML", typeof inC, inC);
  
  initAutoComplete(inC);

  console.log("Init Autocomplete 4");
  console.log("HTML", inD);

  //initAutoComplete(inD);

  console.log("Init Menu 1");
  console.log("HTML", m1);
  var menu = $(m1).menu({
    role: null
  }).hide().menu("instance");

  content.append(inA);
  content.append(inB);
  content.append(inC);
  content.append(inD);
  content.append(m1);
});

function createFromTemplate(item) {
  var base = document.createElement('template');
  var real = document.createElement('input');
  console.log("item:", typeof item, item);
  console.log("real:", typeof real, real);
  base.innerHTML = item;
  var clone = base.content.children[0].cloneNode(true);
  console.log("clone:", typeof clone, clone);
  return clone;
};

function createTempObj(el) {
  var base = $("<template>");
  $(el).appendTo(base);
  return base.children(0).clone("true")[0];
}

function initAutoComplete(el) {
  $(el).autocomplete({
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  });
}

function menuFromTemp() {
  var base = document.createElement('template');
  base.innerHTML = "<ul><li><div>Books</div></li><li><div>Clothing</div></li> <li><div>Electronics</div></li></ul>";
  var menu = base.content.children[0].cloneNode("true");
  return menu;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
<hr />
<template id="template">
  <input>
</template>
```

Input C and D fail to initialize. I commented them out but you can test this on your own. Based on documentation, they should work as expected. If you want to dig into it further, I bet there is an answer out there. If you want to get work done, move away from using `template` for this portion.

It's not clear why you are trying to create a `template` on the fly, why not just create the `input` element on the fly as needed in JavaScript.

Comment: "Based on documentation, they should work as expected" this is what prompted the question in the first place, I don't understand why they're not working based on the documentation I've read. The reason for creating them on the fly like that is that it's part of a much larger project, the code in this question was an easily reproduced snippet. I have actually found a work around for the issue in the mean time :)

Comment: @DarkHippo ok I will try to dig into it further. The function returns an HTML Element in all cases, so it's really unclear why initialization errors. I would expect that on a read only fragment.

Comment: @DarkHippo when I dig into it, this is the line that is failing: `this._addClass( this.menu.element, "ui-autocomplete", "ui-front" );` (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js Line 5784). The error suggests the creation and initialization of `this.menu` fail in the previous statement block.

Comment: Looking at `this.menu = $( "<ul>" ).appendTo( this._appendTo() ).menu( { role: null } ).hide().menu( "instance" );` Line 5774. In this case it's a `null` element which is the default. It should trigger Line 5939: `if ( !element.length ) { element = this.document[ 0 ].body; }` So the next test is to test Menu initalization on a template clone element and see if we get similar results.

Comment: @DarkHippo was able to build a Menu from elements cloned from the template without issue. More investigation needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `div` element instead of a `template` element it works.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  const inputFromTemplate = createFromTemplate(`<input></input>`);

  console.log(input);
  console.log(inputFromTemplate);

  $(input).autocomplete({
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  });

  $(inputFromTemplate).autocomplete({
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  });

  content.append(input);
  content.append(inputFromTemplate);
});

function createFromTemplate(template) {
  const htmlTemplate = document.createElement('div');
  htmlTemplate.innerHTML = template;

  return htmlTemplate.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: For this particular instance, it works, but the createFromTemplate function is also used to dynamically create table rows, which aren't valid child elements of a div, so throw an error, hence the use of 'template'.

Comment: @Dark Hippo. Alright, in that case I shall remove it, since I could not figure out the actual reason yet either. How about using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or Fragments?

Comment: I'd leave it, it might help other people who don't have the table row requirement :)

Comment: I was actually just looking at other options to generate HTML elements from a string. I'm a little loath to change the function because of the amount of regression testing it would need, but if that's the only way...